# Закрытие JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Есть JFrame, у него вроде как есть метод

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(int);
```

Но ему можно задать уже встроенные операции при нажитии на "крестик". Но есть ли возможность как то привязать к нему свой кусок кода, который бы вызывался при закрытии фрейма?

Comment: Вам нужно выполнить какие-то дополнительные действия при закрытии или вы хотите полностью поменять логику работы кнопки?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, выполнить дополнительные действия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два варианта выполнения каких-либо действий при закрытии программы:

1. Более общий вариант, подходящий не только для оконных приложений - навешать shutdown hook на завершение работы JVM

   ```
   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           // Обработка завершения приложения
       }
   });
   ```
2. Навешать на окно обработчик события закрытия окна

   ```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
           // Обработка закрытия окна
       }
   });
   ```